# Regex to find value after nth occurrence of tab

Tags: regex, notepad++, csv

I'm having trouble with a regex in notepad++. I need to find the value (which will be either 1 or 0) after the nth occurrence of tab in a tab delimited file. Text between tabs may differ, so basically there is no pattern except the tab count. Any ideas?

```
^.*?\t0\t
```

This does not work because there may be other places with 0 in line.

Comment: Please provide some sample text and expected output.

Comment: Have a try with: `^(?:[^\t]+\t){5}([01])\b` Change `5` with the number you want to skip.

Comment: What @Toto said :) Only, if empty fields should be allowed, change `+` to `*`. I.e. `^(?:[^\t]*\t){5}([01])\b`.

Comment: @ClasG You did not take into account that `[^\t]`  matches line breaks, too. Besides, OP mentions *there may be other places with 0 in line* - we do not know what OP actually wants to do. Also, the OP pattern matches a `0` as the whole field, the above regex only as  the beginning char of a field.

Comment: what Toto said makes sens and seems to work! also while trying to figure this one came up to this: ^([^\t]*\t){5}0\t([^\t]*\t){17}\r\n

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I simply commented on Toto's answer, which solves the problem OP has. If, as I interpret it, **all** lines have these values, line breaks are't an issue. If not, changing `[^\t]` to `[^\t\r\n]` should do it. And changing `([01])\b` to `([01])[\t\r\n]` addresses your other concern.

Comment: @ClasG Those are minor things. The worst part is that *there may be other places with 0 in line* invalidates Toto's suggestion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think so. Toto's example checks only the 6th field. As OP expresses it - `nth` is `6` in the example. My interpretation of OP is that only that specific field should be tested for `0` or `1`. So it doesn't matter if other fields with zeroes or ones are present. OP's original RE would have matched the desired value in **any** field (except the first ;).

Comment: @Toto FYI. IMO you should submit your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^\t\r\n]+\t){5}([01])(?:\t|$)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  (?:           : start non capture group
    [^\t\r\n]+  : 1 or more character  that is not tab or linebreak
    \t          : a tabulation
  ){5}          : group must appear 5 times (change 5 by any number you want)
  (             : start group 1
    [01]        : 1 digit 0 or 1
  )             : end group 1
  (?:           : non capture group
    \t          : a tabulation
   |            : OR
    $           : end of line
  )             : end group
```

The digit you want is in group #1